# WebRTC on Android Chrome beta in IMS network

Tags: android, webrtc

Recently we are trying to setup a webRTC application which will be running on Android device registered in IMS network. We are using Chrome Beta in Android device since we need to have support of IPv6 addressing scheme. I am having the following issue:

1. The device has IMS APN as well as Internet APN, as a result it has two different IP address for both these APNs.
2. We created the RTCPeerConnection with STUN disabled using the following code snippet:

   ```
   var pc_config =
   {
           "iceServers" : [ {
                   "url" : "stun:0.0.0.0"
           } ],
           "iceTransports": "none"
   };
   var pc_constraints = {'optional': [{'googIPv6': true}]};
   var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config, pc_constraints);
   ```
3. Even though we disabled STUN, we see that STUN binding request is going from the browsers, as per the standards it is the expected behaviour of the browser for consent freshness.

But as per the [webRTC APIs](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#widl-RTCConfiguration-iceTransports), if we use RTCIceTransports Enum (which we did by adding "iceTransports": "none") the ICE engine will not send any packet, but in Chrome beta (Android) we see that this enum has no effect.

The main issue we are having is that, the STUN bind request is going from the Internet APN address to IMS APN address and vice versa, and as a result the IMS network nodes is considering this as a network threat and causing the network to disconnect in the device end.

So our question is (In Chrome Beta Android):

- Is it possible to completely disable the STUN binding request?
- If not can we configure the web RTC APIs to fetch the ICE candidates for the IP addresses of Internet APN only and ensure the STUN bind request goes only from Internet APN to the IP address of the Internet APN of the peer?

We tried the second approach, by filtering the ICE candidate with Internet APN address before sending the SDP offer and answer, so both the peers receives the ICE candidate of the Peer with Internet APN IP address only. But the STUN binding request from the browser is going from the IMS APN IP address to the Internet APN IP address of the peer received in ICE candidate.

Any suggestion to resolve this issue will be a great help to us.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

This completely disables STUN binding requests:

```
var pc_config =  {'iceServers': []};
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, will check this and let you know.